# Auth::check() returns false even if I'm logged in. How to fix this error?

Tags: reactjs, api, single-page-application, laravel-5.8

I'm building a bit web app where user can save his websites.
My problem is that Auth::check() returns false even if me as user I'm logged in when I try to get data throw API.

I use one WebsiteController and I put the route to this controller inside api.php route folder.

I can access http://localhost:8000/website but not http://localhost:8000/api/website.

I'm biginner, please any one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Register API routes in the routes/api.php file. In Laravel, API
   routes and web routes are registered in separate files to avoid
   mixing them all up.
2. After authentication, store the token in local storage and send
   those access token details in each request header.

Ref Sample here : https://medium.com/@Gbxnga/token-based-authentication-with-react-and-laravel-restful-api-83f16581e85

**Assumption  / understanding **: As per the Given brief information, you are tryign to create a CRUD application in react and it calls Laravel API to manage those websites ? 
**Note**: On what you are tryign to accomplish with /api/someroute (is my assumption / understandig is correct?) and where you are calling it in react. Those code snippets you should share and what is expected - when that service call is happneing. Example Return a json and prepoulate list of added websites in home page etc . And instead of happening that, it redirects user to /someroute ? .